# I need to copy office 2010 DVD to usb. Are there hidden files on the DVD

Tags: usb, dvd

I have an Office 2010 DVD and product key. I want to install it on a new computer.

The new computer doesn't have a DVD drive.  When I mount the DVD drive on a Ubuntu PC it says that there are 2 folders (X64 and X86) and 2 files (setup.exe and autorun.inf).  I have copied these to an external usb.  Could there be any hidden or system files that are not listed by Caja?  The "show hidden files" option is on. Will I be able to install from the usb drive?

(I know it is obsolete but the user wants to stay with this release.)

Comment: A reasonable research effort is to try and see.

Comment: another option might be to convert it to an ISO, most modern windows versions would mount it

Answer (score 1):

Office DVD does not contain any hidden files, and the DVD is not bootable.
The installation is simply by running `Setup.exe` from the DVD.

Copying the files is then an effective way to copy the installation,
on condition that you keep the folder structure.